# Valgrind complains on string.append(string)

Tags: c++, string, append, valgrind

I am trying to append one string to another. I declare two global string variables -

```
string grid_filename = "grids/";
string rest;
```

Then I have a function for getting command line arguments. Whenever a user enters a filename in a command line argument, it should be stored in rest and then rest is appended to grid_filename.

```
else if(strcmp(temp.substr(0,16).c_str(), "--grid-filename=") == 0) {
    rest = temp.substr(16,strlen(temp.c_str())-16);
    grid_filename.append(rest);   //line 74!
}
```

Now whenever I run my code, valgrind gives me this error -

```
==5602==  Address 0x45fdc30 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==5602==    at 0x402641D: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
==5602==    by 0x43039F7: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int,     std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==5602==    by 0x4304C77: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==5602==    by 0x4304DA6: std::string::reserve(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==5602==    by 0x43053E9: std::string::append(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14)
==5602==    by 0x804D5AE: get_command_line_args(int, char**) (main.cpp:74)
==5602==    by 0x804F138: main (main.cpp:244)
```

I print out the two addresses of the strings and neither of them match the one valgrind is saying is 0 bytes. What am I missing here?

I believe this leads to my second error because I pass grid_filename to another function that sends the string over a tcp connection. Valgrind tells me

```
==5660== Syscall param socketcall.send(msg) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==5660==    at 0x404A9B1: send (socket.S:64)
==5660==    by 0x804F7C8: main (main.cpp:364)
```

Can anyone explain to me what the problem is? Any help would be appreciated. I can supply more about the code if needed.

Comment: The first error message you give is not complete. The real error message must be right above the text you pasted, something about reading or writing to 0x45fdc30. Then, valgrind prints the message you pasted, which tells you something about that address.

Comment: The second error message I posted occurs right above the first I posted. I figured they were separate so I wrote about them separately. The whole message should start with the "Syscall param socketcall.send(msg) points to unaddressable byte(s)" followed by the "Address 0x45fdc30 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd" message.

Comment: OK, so we need to see your call to send, because apparently that gets passed an invalid pointer, which happens to point just *after* the memory allocated by grid_filename.append().

Comment: Are you aware that `std::string` offers `==` for comparison, and `length()` for length?

Comment: We'll be able to help you more efficiently if you provide a *complete*, *short* program that demonstrates the error. Remove everything that doesn't contribute to the problem, then post that **short** program in your question. See: http://sscce.org/.

Comment: The error was in my send call. I just hadn't changed the length of bytes to send to string_to_send.length() yet. Thank you for all of the tips in the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

About your first error: we had false positives in valgrind.  Check the [documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) to suppress these, especially if they are not pointing to your code (and you have checked that they don't actually cause problems)

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this is not a response, this is not a code review site... but really I can't stare at this and walk away.*

First, some functions that really help in a toolbox:

```
// Some free functions (because there are too many string types)
inline char const* c_str(std::string const& s) { return s.c_str(); }
inline size_t size(std::string const& s) { return s.size(); }

inline char const* c_str(char const* s) { return s; }
inline size_t size(char const* s) { return std::strlen(s); }

template <size_t N>
char const* c_str(char const (&s)[N]) { return s; }
template <size_t N>
size_t size(char const (&s)[N]) { return N - 1; }

// A helper function (lowest common denominator)
inline bool beginsWith(char const* big, size_t const bigSize,
                       char const* small, size_t const smallSize)
{
  if (bigSize < smallSize) { return false; }
  return std::memcmp(big, small, smallSize) == 0;
}

// The actual function, doing the adaptation from the various forms of string
template <typename T, typename U>
bool beginsWith(T& big, U& small) {
    return beginsWith(c_str(big), size(big), c_str(small), size(small));
}

// same with endsWith
```

And then you can rewrite the code quite efficiently (no extra memory allocation) and with more readability too:

```
static std::string const GridFilenameOpt = "--grid-filename=";

// ...
else if (beginsWith(temp, GridFilenameOpt)) {
    grid_filename.append(temp, GridFilenameOpt.size(), std::string::npos);
}
```

Which won't help much for the actual question since you're not showing the code producing the error.

Comment: If you want `beginsWith`, why not just `bool beginsWith(string const &a, string const &b) { return a.compare(0, b.length(), b);}`?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I don't like the idea of creating a spurious temporary `string` just for the sake of doing this comparison. The problem is that enumerating all combinations of the 3 strings types of C++ (`std::string` and `char const*` plus the optimizable `char const (&)[N]`) is boring, so I tend to unify their interface into the lowest common denominator (actually... at home I use a class similar to `llvm::StringRef` for this unification).

Comment: The function above shouldn't create any new string for the comparison. It's just using the `compare` member function, which allows you to specify a starting point and length for the comparison. It is only written for `string`, but would be trivial to generalize for `basic_string` in general. At the same time, using `memcmp` is pretty restrict in itself...

Comment: @JerryCoffin: `beginsWith(temp, "--grid-filename=")` would create a temporary however.